# Spring Boot Actuator Info Endpoint Version from Gradle File

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I'd like the `/info` actuator endpoint from my Spring Boot (1.2.4.RELEASE) application to return the version as specified in the `build.gradle` file.

In my `build.gradle` file I have a line as so:

```
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
```

I am using yaml configuration file.  Right now I have the version duplicated as so in `application.yml`:

```
info:
    build:
        version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exact use case is spelled out in the Boot docs:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-automatic-expansion-gradle

So in your build.gradle do this

```
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
processResources {
    expand(project.properties)
}
```

Your application.yml

```
info:
  build:
    version: ${version}
```

1. Make sure to escape any spring placeholders so it doesn't conflict with Gradle. Both use ${} as the replacement token. ${key} should become \${key} . This will affect anything in src/main/resources.
2. Clean/build and deploy your war/jar. Don't run it from your IDE or the placeholder won't be replaced.

Comment: That references a `project.properties` file though, so I don't see the connection with the Gradle app version...  Do you know how the `project.properties` fits in.

Comment: It's not referring to a file. It's the Gradle Project object. Be careful if you have other spring ${} placeholders in your yml files as noted in the link. Those need to be escaped.

Comment: This solution apparently does not work for Spring Boot 2 applications: `org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'info.build.version' to java.lang.Object`... caused by `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in value \"${version}\"`

Comment: @jst Yeah, this only works for Spring boot 1.x.  It would be good to have a Spring Boot 2.x answer as well,.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-info-actuator-custom

Works for Spring Boot 2.x

Comment: @JoshuaDavis, with regards to the link; we would still require a hard coded version in the Gradle file & in the InfoContributor class.

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to the `build.gradle` file. It is not necessary to create an `InfoContributor` class.

```groovy
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '<version>'
}

springBoot {
  buildInfo()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    etc...
}
```

Query `http://host:port/actuator/info` and you will see something like...

```json
{
  "build": {
    "artifact": "spring-example",
    "name": "spring-example",
    "time": "2020-01-30T09:47:33.551Z",
    "version": "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
    "group": "com.example"
  }
}
```

N.b. Tested with 2.2.4.RELEASE

Comment: What is "N.b." an abbreviation of?

Comment: @M.Justin It's an english abbreviation for "note" or "take note", see  https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/nb